# Use some parts of babel polyfill

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs

I just want to use `Map` from ES2015 by using Babel but not others, but the babel-polifill is too big,
Is there any way to use some parts of it?

Comment: Why are you wanting babel is this case? Just add some `Map` polyfill and job done

Comment: Not babel,but babel-polyfill, `Map` is just for example,  and i want to use some parts of babel-polyfill because of the  file size.

Comment: I think i have found solution , by `require ('core-js/es6/map')`

Comment: with babel 6 the above approach does not work? does anyone know how to pick and choose babel polyfills in babel 6?